# UITextView Font not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using arial font in UITextView but i want to change to Myriad but its not changing

```
    textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad" size:20];
```

Answer (score 7):

Myriad font is not supported by iOS by default, so if you want to use it you'll need to add font file (e.g. *.ttf) to your application resources and make couple of setup steps to make that font visible to system.

Detailed tutorial about how to use custom fonts in iOS application can be found [here](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/) for example

Answer (score 2):

If You are using XIB and taking IBOutlet ,then select your `UITextView` and press `Command + T` to show fonts and change it accordingly. and by the way `Myriad` font is not supported by iOS by default.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper name of font ,for example

**textView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad" size:20];**
and never set the system font size at that time , when  you using the custom font  that may create a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour but for textview if you want to change font in code you should first check in storyboard that textview is **selectable**. If not than it wont change font from code. Strange but thats is true.

Also try this:

Please call all your code in viewDidLoadSubviews method! Than works. I have many problems when chanhing font size, style i viewDidLoad or viewWillApperar methods.
So just move your code in viewDidLoadSubviews method. You can use flag to change fonts only once since this method can be called many times :]