# IOS: problem with a label

Tags: ios, label

I want to create a label with "ComicSans" font but it don't work, why?
I write my label and when I go to change its font, it don't change...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView Font not changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923200/uitextview-font-not-changing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**These are**](http://iosfonts.com/) the fonts that are supported on iPad & iPhone. "ComicSans" is not a part of it. Maybe you need to select something else...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need .ttf files of all fonts.
Search for fontlabel... [link](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/1d19393664fe92b6786917dba16547b39a2e10f1)